# Write a function that takes in a list of numbers and adds one to each of the original numbers?

Tags: python

#Write a function named add_one_to_all that takes in a list of numbers and adds one to each of the original numbers

```
assert add_one_to_all([0, 0, 0]) == [1, 1, 1]

assert add_one_to_all([1, 2, 3]) == [2, 3, 4]

assert add_one_to_all([6, 7, 8]) == [7, 8, 9]
```

I've tried this

```
def my_list ([x,y,z]):
  
new_list = [x+1 for x in my_list]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def add_one_to_all(my_list): 
  return [x+1 for x in my_list]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def add_one_to_all(integer):
    return integer+1
  
int_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  
# Adding one on each integer
# using list comprehension.
output_list = [add_one_to_all(i) for i in int_list]
  
print(output_list)
```

> The output will be **[2,3,4,5,6]**

Comment: Why is this not correct answer? Result is as it should be.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `map`

```
  l = [1, 2, 3]
  
  print(list(map(lambda x:x+1, l)))
```

result

```
[2, 3, 4]
```